# What is the method to solve the relation: $a_n = \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}}$, with $a_0 = k_0$ and $a_1 = k_1$?

Tags: recurrence-relations

Below I did a development of the recurrence starting in $k_0$ and $k_1$. (with $k_0, k_1 \neq 0$)

Note that the sequence is alternated and we get a constants values for each class of $n$:

$$a_n =
\begin{cases}
k_0,  & \text{if $n$ is {0,6,12,...}} \\
k_1, & \text{if $n$ is {1,7,13,...}} \\
k_1/k_0, & \text{if $n$ is {2,8,14,...}} \\
1/k_0, & \text{if $n$ is {3,9,15,...}} \\
1/k_1, & \text{if $n$ is {4,10,16,...}} \\
k_0/k_1, & \text{if $n$ is {5,11,17,...}} \\
\end{cases}$$

That is, the sequence:

$$k_0, k_1, \frac{k_1}{k_0}, \frac{1}{k_0}, \frac{1}{k_1}, \frac{k_0}{k_1}, k_0, k_1, \frac{k_1}{k_0}, \frac{1}{k_0}, \frac{1}{k_1}, \frac{k_0}{k_1}, k_0, k_1, ...$$

My question is whether this method is correct and safe to resolve this type of relation?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Your work looks correct.  Once you have determined that $a_6=a_0$ and $a_7=a_1$, since $a_n$ depends only on $a_{n-1}$ and $a_{n-2}$, it follows that $a_{6k+r}=a_r$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$ by mathematical induction